# SQL query with having function to only includes parts of another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, where-clause, having

I am trying to find fact_order_id's that have **beverage only items**. This would make the fact_order_id not include any food items.

```
fact_order_id
fact_order_line_id
category Group
category Name
```

I have used 2 separate SQL Queries below. When I go back and check my work, I notice some fact_order_id's in the output **aren't** beverage only orders. Here are the 2 separate SQL Queries that give me the same output:

```
select fact_order_id
from my_table
group by fact_order_id
having avg((category_group like 'Beverage%')::int) = 1;


select fact_order_id
from my_table
group by fact_order_id
having avg(CASE WHEN category_group like 'Beverage%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1;
```

Both of the outputs above give me the same number of rows. Whenever I cross check the fact_order_id, some of them would include an output with food items.

This fact_order_id shouldn't be included in my output since there are other non-beverage items on the order. There are 2 Category Group that have a beverage name (**Beverage (non-alcohol) & Beverage (specialty)**). Is there a better way of creating a SQL Query to only have an output of fact_order_id's that are beverage only orders?

**I am using PostgreSQL Version: 08.00.0002**

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how old your PostgreSQL is, can you please try this?

```
select fact_order_id
  from my_table
 group by fact_order_id
having bool_and((category_group like 'Beverage%'));
```

Based on your comment, can you please try this query and share your results?

```
select fact_order_id, category_group, category_name,
       (category_group like 'Beverage%') as is_beverage
  from my_table
 where fact_order_id = '1 292 757'
```

You can join back into your table in your checks to see if there is a problem.  The following query is nonsensical from a SQL standpoint, but it would automate your cross-checking:

```
with bev_orders as (
  select fact_order_id
    from my_table
   group by fact_order_id
  having bool_and((category_group like 'Beverage%'))
)
select *
  from my_table t
  join bev_orders b 
    on b.fact_order_id = t.fact_order_id
 where t.category_group not like 'Beverage%' ;
```

Comment: I am still getting the same exact row count output as the queries I have listed above. I will accept this answer since this query is using a different function (bool_and) than anything I've tried before.

Comment: @Natasha  I do not understand how this would cause your example `fact_order_id` to be returned.  There is no need for you to accept this answer if it is not working for you.  I have updated my answer with a query that might help us figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: The true/false works per category group. I wouldn't want this `fact_order_id` to return on the main SQL Query since there is at least one false in the `fact_order_id`. When cross checking, I haven't found a `fact_order_id` (yet) in the output that includes a food item.

Comment: @Natasha  I added a check query to my answer.

Comment: Does "No Rows To Show" as the output mean the original query is correct?

Comment: That "No Rows To Show" means the last query I added is pulling `fact_order_id` values for which there are no non-beverage items, but I still wonder how the other queries could have failed you.

Comment: I just crossed checked your query along with my others. All of the `fact_order_id` are coming back with the beverages. Whenever I search the master table for some `fact_order_id`, some have a food item as well.

Comment: @Natasha  I cannot see how that is possible.  Can you please run the second query with one of the `fact _order_id` values to see whether the `like` part of the query is evaluating correctly?

Answer (score 0):

How about excluding fact_order_ids which you know aren't good?

```sql
select distinct fact_order_id
from my_table
where fact_order_id not in (
    select distinct fact_order_id
    from my_table
    where not category_group like 'Beverage%'
);
```

Comment: I have thousands of rows for my output so excluding fact_order_id's wouldn't work unless I checked every single fact_order_id separately.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I'm suggesting a query which works by finding the inverse of what you're looking for, fact_order_ids which DO have a non-beverage item, and then returning all fact_order_ids that aren't in that first set.

Comment: I am getting the same exact row count output as the queries I have listed above. I am in the process of cross checking the my_table for the output fact_order_ids you have shown.